# How to store a VBA program independent of the Office document?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have an Excel sheet. I add some programs to it (VBA) to make my workflow smoother. Then, after some time, I need another sheet which is very similar to the old one - especially because I want to use the same VBA program in it.

Is there a way to move the program from my old sheet to the new one save from copying the old sheet?

Comment: Have you thought about making an [addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx)?

Comment: +1 to @DougGlancy. If you need it to be independent of the Application (i.e., to work in Word, PPT, Excel, etc.) then you can use a COM Add-In.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export the modules to a .bas file you could then import that code to any Excel sheet you needed it in.

It would also allow some customisation, as any changes you make after you import the module in will not have any effect on the original.